# My cat was cross-eyed, now she’s not. Why?

Tags: cats, biology

I got my cat half a year ago at a rescue centre, she was very cross-eyed, the longer she has been in my home the more her cross-eyed-ness has gone. Is this normal? And what has caused this?

[image]

Comment: maybe your cat was drunk before, I have a friend that becomes cross-eyed when drunk !

Comment: Interesting I went on google to find the same answer. My snowshoe Siamese used to be super cross eyed when I first rescued her. I have a lot of pics and video. Now I’ve had her like 2 years she’s barely cross eyed anymore. Others have mentioned the same thing. I really wonder if they grow out of it or if a stable environment helped. Maybe both or Neither? IDK. Curious.

Answer (score 4):

Crossed eyes is a relatively common hereditary condition in cats, most common in Siamese cats, cats with blue eyes, or other breeds closely related to the Siamese. If it is hereditary, there is no concern or treatment, and the cat can still live a normal happy life, even with vision that's a little off. But crossed eyes can have other causes as well, such as disease or physical trauma, and those things might need to be treated. Therefore, if you haven't already, consult with your vet about your cat's condition, to make sure that no treatment is necessary.

If its crossed eyes are indeed hereditary, it's definitely not going to spontaneously recover, as that condition is permanent. However, there are different circumstances in which the crossed eyes can be more or less pronounced. The condition is more or less noticeable when the cat is focusing closer or farther away, for example. There is also intermittent crossed eyes, where the eyes become crossed when the animal is tired or sick, but other times its eyes will track normally.